# Bib file does not update in TexMakerX when I build the file

Tags: biblatex, texstudio

I am using `Bib.bib` file for all the references. When I use `\cite{someref}` it works fine for the first time but when I update the `Bib.bib` file it does not get the updated information, it just show the previous information. I just build the file by quick build button.

Comment: Welcome! We need some information. How do you edit your bib-file? Is it generated by `filecontents`? How did you setup the `quick-build-button`?

Comment: You may want to update to the current version, now called TeXstudio.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you are not running BibTeX at all. When writing a `.tex` document you need to run several prgrams on it (or generated files) depending on what your document contain. Some of these are `latex`, `pdflate` and `bibtex`. In Texmaker these appear as buttons in the Tools menu

[image]

Now, `latex` generates a `.dvi` file, `pdflatex` generates a `.pdf` file and so the vies options are there to open the document, and the ones with an `->` are there to let you convert from one format to another.

When writing LaTeX document you need to:

- run `latex` twice to update internal references and table of contents;
- run `latex`, then `bibtex` then `latex` again to update the bibliography; and
- run `latex`, then `bibtex`, then `latex` twice to update the bibliography and references to it.

Note the the last two also updates the internal references (e.g. made with `\label` and `\ref`) and the table of contetns.

as the picture above shows you can use hotkeys to run pdflatex and bibtex with F6 and F11 on your keyboard respectively, so pressing F6 F11 F6 F6 one at a time (and waiting for texmaker to finish each time) you will update everything in your document (unless you are also making a subject index or something of the sort).

Now to explain what happens when you use quickbuild. In the texmaker configuration:

[image]

you can see what the quickbuild does, and change this. This menu is accesed through the options menu

[image]

**EDIT**

I did not reallize that it was a question about TexStudie/TexMakerX and not TexMaker. The problem might still be the same, but of course the menus might look different.

Comment: Please be aware that the OP is using Texstudio, not Texmaker. Texstudio started as a fork of Texmaker some years ago, but the menus and configuration may be quite different between the two in the newest versions.

Comment: @matth: Ohh, i did not realize that. Maybe I was to fast. The tag said taxmaker, but i did not notice that it said TexMakerx instead of TexMaker in the title. I will keep this possibility in mind next time. I hope the similarity is large enough so that me answer helps.